# Time Zone in ruby

Tags: ruby, time

I am hosting a program that is servicing people from timezone GMT+1000. However, my timezone is at GMT +800, and people who login into my server sees time at +800.

I am using Sinatra and the time data is stored is POSIX time. Is there a way to show the time in GMT +1000 for my user's convenience?

Thanks.

Comment: Anyway, found solution to it.
time = Time.new
time.localtime("+10:00")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Works on Ruby 1.9.2

```
time=Time.new
=> 2012-02-09 09:52:10 +0800 
time.localtime("+10:00")
=> 2012-02-09 11:52:10 +1000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `offset` utility present in `Time` class  of ruby n determine the time to your desired time.